# Dropbox API logout then redirect

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

In a 3rd party app, using dropbox API,
I'm trying to handle 2 or more Dropbox user accounts.
Which mean I try to logout a user (and keep its tokens valid) then login another.
to logout I use : https://www.dropbox.com/logout
However, when logging out, is it possible to redirect to my official redirect_uri ?
Something like: https://www.dropbox.com/logout?client_id=myclientid&redirect_uri=myredirecturi

Answer (score 1):

No, the Dropbox API doesn't offer a way to do this. We'll consider it a feature request.

Comment: Ok, I'm asking because I'm using DropBox API in a iOS app, and for authorisation I'm using a SFSafariViewController, so it's kind difficult to logout a previous user and login an other one.

Comment: @Greg any update/way to implement this? I want the same in my app too.

Comment: @Rohit Not exactly as described here, but [the `force_reauthentication` parameter on /oauth2/authorize](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#oauth2-authorize) would be the right way to do this now.